# Issue with strsplit not storing searched field

Tags: r, regex

I am running a regex query using R

```
df<- c("955 - 959 Fake Street","95-99 Fake Street","4-9 M4 Ln","95 - 99 Fake Street","99 Fake Street")

955 - 959 Fake Street
95-99 Fake Street
4-9 M4 Ln
95 - 99 Fake Street
99 Fake Street
```

I am attempting to sort these addresses into two columns

I expected:

```
strsplit(df, "\\d+(\\s*-\\s*\\d+)?", perl=T)
```

would split up the numbers on the left and the rest of the address on the right.

The result I am getting is:

```
[1] ""             " Fake Street"
[1] ""             " Fake Street"
[1] ""    " M"  " Ln"
[1] ""             " Fake Street"
[1] ""             " Fake Street"
```

The strsplit function appears to be delete the field used to split the string. Is there any way I can preserve it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use lookbehinds and lookaheads to split at the space between a number and the character:

```
strsplit(df, "(?<=\\d)\\s(?=[[:alpha:]])", perl = TRUE)
# [[1]]
# [1] "955 - 959"   "Fake Street"
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] "95-99"       "Fake Street"
# 
# [[3]]
# [1] "4-9" "M4"  "Ln" 
# 
# [[4]]
# [1] "95 - 99"     "Fake Street"
# 
# [[5]]
# [1] "99"          "Fake Street"
```

This, however also splits at the space between `"M4"` and `"Ln"`. If your addresses are always of the format "number (possible range) followed by rest of the address" you could extract the two parts separately (as @d.b suggested):

```
splitDf <- data.frame(
        numberPart = sub("(\\d+(\\s*-\\s*\\d+)?)(.*)", "\\1", df),
        rest = trimws(sub("(\\d+(\\s*-\\s*\\d+)?)(.*)", "\\3", df)))

splitDf
#   numberPart        rest
# 1  955 - 959 Fake Street
# 2      95-99 Fake Street
# 3        4-9       M4 Ln
# 4    95 - 99 Fake Street
# 5         99 Fake Street
```

Comment: @Jamzy Isn't a one liner simpler?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Yep, both answers worked. ikops solution also solved an additional problem with M4 Ln.

Comment: @Jamzy My one `strsplit` solution also solves it because the pattern only matches once being anchored at the start of the string with `^`.

Answer (score 2):

You are almost there, just append `\\K\\s*` to your regex and prepend with the `^`, start of string anchor:

```
df<- c("955 - 959 Fake Street","95-99 Fake Street","4-9 M4 Ln","95 - 99 Fake Street","99 Fake Street")
strsplit(df, "^\\d+(\\s*-\\s*\\d+)?\\K\\s*", perl=T)
```

The `\K` is a match reset operator that discards the text msatched so far, so after matching 1+ digits, optionally followed with `-` enclosed with 0+ whitespaces and 1+ digits at the start of the string, this whole text is dropped. Ony 0+ whitespaces get it into the match value, and they will be split on.

See the [R demo](http://ideone.com/p9VCmp) outputting:

```
[[1]]
[1] "955 - 959"   "Fake Street"

[[2]]
[1] "95-99"       "Fake Street"

[[3]]
[1] "4-9"   "M4 Ln"

[[4]]
[1] "95 - 99"     "Fake Street"

[[5]]
[1] "99"          "Fake Street"
```